# Adicionar elemento num Array

Tags: java, array, loop

Preciso adicionar `lista.get(i)` num array, será adicionado no array com o valor da *key* `spec_linha-criativa` alterado. Porém, no meu código eu sempre perco a referência e quando `j = 1` a minha lista está com os mesmo valores. Por exemplo, quando o laço é executado: j = 0 o elemento 0 da lista está correto, quando j = 1 o elemento 1 está correto mas o elemento 0 **se torna igual o 1**. Como corrigir isso? Eu já dou o *new* no objeto a cada interação para evitar isto mas ocorre.

```
private List<BasicDBObject> linhaCriativa(List<BasicDBObject> linhas) {
    List<BasicDBObject> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < linhas.size(); i++) {
        if (linhas.get(i).toMap().containsKey("spec_linha-criativa")) {
            String[] linhaCriativa = linhas.get(i).get("spec_linha-criativa").toString().split(";");
            if (linhaCriativa.length > 1) {
                for (int j = 0; j < linhaCriativa.length; j++) {
                    BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
                    dbObject = linhas.get(i);
                    dbObject.replace("spec_linha-criativa", linhaCriativa[j]);
                    lista.add(dbObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return lista;
}
```

> Já tive o mesmo problema de "perder" referência mas não consigo
>   aplicar aqui
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658869/why-cant-i-concatenate-the-json

Comment: `lista` e `linha` sempre terão o mesmo tamanho?

Comment: São as mesmas coisas, trouxe por parâmetro duas vezes para tentar ver se conseguia alterar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, isto daqui está errado:

```
BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
dbObject = linhas.get(i);
```

O primeiro valor atribuído vai ser perdido porque logo após um outro valor é atribuído sem que o primeiro seja usado para nada. Além disso, como nesta parte você está iterando o `j`, mas pegando com o `i`, isso vai sempre pegar o mesmo objeto na iteração e aplicar o `replace` várias vezes no mesmo objeto. Acho que o que você quer não é alterar o `BasicDBObject`, mas sim criar um novo `BasicDBObject` com as alterações.

Para simplificar o seu código, vou aplicar o *for-each* nos seus dois laços e nos `if`s, inverter a condição e usar o `continue`:

```
private List<BasicDBObject> linhaCriativa(List<BasicDBObject> linhas) {
    List<BasicDBObject> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    for (BasicDBObject db : linhas) {
        if (!db.toMap().containsKey("spec_linha-criativa")) continue;
        String[] linhaCriativa = db.get("spec_linha-criativa").toString().split(";");
        if (linhaCriativa.length == 0) continue;
        for (String criativa : linhaCriativa) {
            BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
            dbObject = db;
            dbObject.replace("spec_linha-criativa", criativa);
            lista.add(dbObject);
        }
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Agora vamos tentar corrigir o problema:

```
private List<BasicDBObject> linhaCriativa(List<BasicDBObject> linhas) {
    List<BasicDBObject> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    for (BasicDBObject db : linhas) {
        if (!db.toMap().containsKey("spec_linha-criativa")) continue;
        String[] linhaCriativa = db.get("spec_linha-criativa").toString().split(";");
        if (linhaCriativa.length == 0) continue;
        for (String criativa : linhaCriativa) {
            BasicDBObject dbObject = db.copy();
            dbObject.replace("spec_linha-criativa", criativa);
            lista.add(dbObject);
        }
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Observe que eu inventei um método `copy()`. Este método vai criar uma cópia do `BasicDBObject`. Desta forma, eu posso criar várias cópias de cada instância e alterar cada uma delas de um jeito diferente sem alterar a original.

Talvez isso ainda dê algum problema que você queira manter uma cópia inalterada quando não houver nenhum `"spec_linha-criativa"` para substituir. Neste caso:

```
private List<BasicDBObject> linhaCriativa(List<BasicDBObject> linhas) {
    List<BasicDBObject> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    for (BasicDBObject db : linhas) {
        String linhaCriativa = db.toMap().containsKey("spec_linha-criativa")
                ? db.get("spec_linha-criativa").toString().split(";")
                : new String[0];
        if (linhaCriativa.length == 0) {
            lista.add(db.copy());
            continue;
        }
        for (String criativa : linhaCriativa) {
            BasicDBObject dbObject = db.copy();
            dbObject.replace("spec_linha-criativa", criativa);
            lista.add(dbObject);
        }
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Comment: Uau, eu sempre tenho esse problema de "perder o objeto" quando quero substitui-lo. Bem esclarecedor, obrigada